# Use jackson to wrap subclass attributes into a sub-key

Tags: java, json, jackson

My REST service needs to return messages of format:

```
{
  "code": 1000,
  "message": "Success",
  "description": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "custId": "00000023401443",
      "engName": "MISTER NORWAYTEST'S PASSPORT",
    }
  ]
}
```

where the first tier of the JSON message is basically like a message header to provide technical details about message delivery while the "data" key contains the actual business information.

If I were to create a class to reflect this, I would by default come out with something that looks like this:

```
public class ResponseModel<T> implements Serializable{
    private Integer code;
    private String message;
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty(value = "data")
    private T dataObj;
}
```

but doing it this way causes my controllers to all return the same object with no real business context value to the class name and reduces readability:

```
@GetMapping("/profile/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> getProfile(@PathVariable String userId) {
...
}
```

What I would like to do is to use ResponseModel as a superclass and then inherit them into subclasses with real business context names (e.g. Customer or Account). But in order to adhere to the required JSON format, I need to ensure that attributes of the subclass as wrapped into the "data" key.

Is there a way that I can do that? Using @JsonRootName would also wrap the superclass properties as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your the format you want is right here :

```
"data": *[* <---- HERE THAT BRACKET
```

If you want a bracket that means your data is a list so you need to fix it by making `dataObj` a list :

```
@JsonProperty(value = "data")
private List<T> dataObj;
```

Now i don't see the point of subclassing ResponseModel you could just do the following :

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> myControllerMethod(){
    List<Account> list = myService.readAccounts();
    return new ResponseModel<Account>(list);//default code OK,...
}
```

If you make your Business classes inherits ResponseModel which is only a wrapper to handle controller's result, you will be mixing your business layer with controller's specific layer which is not a good idea.

> but doing it this way causes my controllers to all return the same object with no real business context value to the class name and reduces readability:

In a Java's controller, you're suppose to have very very few lines, basically, call a service, check the answer/handle exceptions, return the response. So I don't see any problem of readability because if this. If you talk about the generic returned value, just name properly your methods.